# Como selecionar todos os elementos "vazios"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Existe alguma forma de se selecionar todos os elementos vazios de uma página?

Por algum motivo que não sei explicar, o código abaixo não seleciona os inputs sem texto em minha página:

```
$("input[value=''], select[value=''], textarea[value='']");
```

Eu sei que eu posso obter todos os `input`'s, `select`'s e `textarea`'s vazios com um laço, se eu primeiro obtiver todos os elementos com algo como `$("input, select, textarea")` e depois verificar o retorno do método `val` para cada um deles. No entanto, gostaria de saber se existe algum seletor especial apenas para controles vazios, que tenha uma performance melhor do que a filtragem por força bruta.

Comment: $('input:text[value=""]');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma mais simples é `input:not([value]),input[value='']`:

http://jsfiddle.net/4rB65/

```
<input type="text">
<input type="text" value>
<input type="text" value="">
<input type="text" value="foo">

$(function() {
    $('input:not([value]),input[value=""]').css('border', 'solid 1px red');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Aparentemente, quando se usa `[value=""]` ele observa somente o **atributo** `value`, não a **propriedade** `value`. Ou seja, o valor que havia no markup, não o valor atual. Exemplo:

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" value="" />
```

O primeiro o seletor nunca vai pegar. O segundo, sempre vai (mesmo se você editar e colocar um valor nele).

Observando [os seletores disponíveis pelo jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), receio não haver nenhum que satisfaça seu requisito. A resposta do @Gustavo Rodrigues ([preservada por @bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/7307/215)) seria portanto um dos únicos *workarounds* disponíveis (i.e. filtrar os resultados pelo valor da propriedade `value`).

Comment: O mesmo se aplica para o `textarea:empty`. Ver [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/Sr2dG/)

Comment: @utluiz Verdade, pois os sub-elementos do `textarea` são usados para **inicializar** sua propriedade `value`, mas fora isso são deixados intactos. Só se alguém atribuir explicitamente os atributos dos inputs/select (via `.attr`) ou manipular explicitamente os descendentes do `textarea` é que o resultado iria mudar.

Answer (score 4):

> No entanto, gostaria de saber se existe algum seletor especial apenas para controles vazios, que tenha uma performance melhor do que a filtragem por força bruta.

**Resposta: Não, não existe.**

Até mesmo a sua alternativa utilizando `value=""` não é 100% satisfatória em filtrar os elementos com value vazio.

Utilizando o seletor:

```
$('input[value=""]') //...
```

Você receberia dos seguintes elementos:

```
<input type="text">              <!-- não retornaria (mas deveria retornar) -->
<input type="text" value>        <!-- retornaria -->
<input type="text" value="">     <!-- retornaria -->
<input type="text" value="foo">  <!-- não retornaria -->
```

Como você pode perceber, o primeiro item do exemplo, mesmo sem possuir o atributo "value" e estando vazio, não é retornado como objeto pelo seletor.

A melhor solução ainda seria realizar um loop por todos os elementos que você quer verificar utilizando a função jQuery `.val()` por exemplo, para filtrar os elementos vazios.

---

### Exemplo de solução, utilizando loop:

```
var s = $('input');
s.each(function(){
    var t = $(this);
    if(t.val()){
        t.addClass('exclua-me');
    }
});
var vazios = s.not('.exclua-me'); //aqui você tem os inputs vazios
```

**[`EXEMPLO NO FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/6p5P2/)**

Comment: O 4º caso deveria ser "não retornaria", não?

Comment: @mgibsonbr Sim, eu que comi mosca, corrigido.

Comment: O problema dessa abordagem com `[value...]` é que não pega os campos que tiverem sido limpos via js.

Comment: Se eu pudesse votar duas vezes, daria mais um voto, pelo trabalho de citar cada caso possível.

Answer (score 3):

Não existe um seletor para isso.

Para tratar tudo de uma vez só, eu sugiro a abordagem que o @Gustavo Rodrigues havia postado (mas apagou):

```
$('input, select, textarea').filter(function () {
    return !this.value.trim();
});
```

Comment: O `textarea:empty` continue retornando o elemento se o mesmo for editado após o carregamento da página. Ver [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/Sr2dG/)

Comment: Certo, excluí a menção ao :empty

Answer (score 2):

Para o que você postou funcionar, os valores devem estar explicitamente definidos como `value=""`, e então será possível selecionar os elementos `input`, `select` e `textarea` que você quer com a seguinte expressão:

```
$("input[value=''], select:has(option[value='']:selected), textarea:empty")
```

**EDIT**

Dei uma melhorada na expressão para selecionar também os que não possuirem o atributo value:

```
$("input[value=''], input:not([value]), select:has(option[value='']:selected), select:has(option:not([value]):selected), textarea:empty")
```

Poxa, infelizmente, parece que esses seletores só conseguem ver os valores originais impressos no HTML, e não os valores corrente... com exceção do seletor para o `select`.

**EDIT 2**

Você pode, entretanto, criar o seu próprio seletor, como o descrito no código desta resposta do SOEN: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15031698/195417

```
jQuery.extend(
  jQuery.expr[':'],
  {
    /// check that a field's value property has a particular value
    'field-value': function (el, indx, args) {
      var a, v = $(el).val();
      if ( (a = args[3]) ) {
        switch ( a.charAt(0) ) {
          /// begins with
          case '^':
            return v.substring(0,a.length-1) == a.substring(1,a.length);
          break;
          /// ends with
          case '$':
            return v.substr(v.length-a.length-1,v.length) == 
              a.substring(1,a.length);
          break;
          /// contains
          case '*': return v.indexOf(a.substring(1,a.length)) != -1; break;
          /// equals
          case '=': return v == a.substring(1,a.length); break;
          /// not equals
          case '!': return v != a.substring(1,a.length); break;
          /// equals
          default: return v == a; break;
        }
      }
      else {
        return !!v;
      }
    }
  }
);
```

E depois usar assim:

- para valores que começam com "teste": `$('input:field-value(^teste)');`
- para valores que contêm "teste": `$('input:field-value(*teste)');`
- para valores que terminam com "teste": `$('input:field-value($teste)');`
- para valores que não são iguais a "teste": `$('input:field-value(!teste)');`
- para valores que são iguais a "teste": `$('input:field-value(=teste)');`

Não esqueça de dar um upvote lá pro cara do SOEN se achar essa uma boa solução... o mérito não é meu. =)

Answer (score 1):

Neste [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DVc5E/4/) comtemplamos a coleta dos elementos que não possui valor contudo apenas é possível obter o estado inicial dos campos.

Basicamente

```
$('input:not([value])')
```

pega todos os `input` que não possuem o atributo `value` preenchidos, e

```
$('input[value=""]')
```

pega todos os elementos que possuem o atributo `value` sem valor ou vazio.
a junção dos dois em um formulário com o tratamento para saber se há `select` e `textarea`
vazios ficaria:

```
$('form input:not([value]), input[value=""], textarea:empty, select:empty');
```

Mas só isso não resolve, pois os três primeiros seletores pegam os campos cujo estado inicial seja vazio, ou seja, se o usuário alterar ou preenche - los, esses campos ainda continuarão sendo selecionados pela consulta.

Particularmente para resolver o problema, eu prefiro utilizar o código deste [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DVc5E/5/) que evita que um campo que está preenchido do servidor seja selecionado e ao mesmo tempo, ainda limita-se aos `input` que por padrão vem sem valor do servidor.

Comment: Você está usando um laço, não um seletor nativo.

Comment: Não entendi. Testei (colocando um valor num dos campos e clicando no botão) e apareceu `2 empty fields`. Fiz algo errado?

Comment: @TiagoCésarOliveira o seletor é `'form input:not([value]), input[name=""], select:empty, textarea:empty'` o laço é apenas para pegar todos os valores selecionados e exibí-los

Comment: @mgibsonbr realmente, após edição os valores continuam vindo, por isso, ajustei a minha resposta.